# Javascript change source executes just the first line

Tags: javascript, iphone, iframe, user-agent

Hey guys I want to change the source of some iframes if you load my page with an iphone. My Problem is that it works but just the first line the other two iframes dosn't get changed. Some ideas how to fix that?

```
     if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
       document.getElementById("iframe-startpage-mobile").src = "placeholder_1/index.html";
       document.getElementById("iframe-vrapp-mobile").src = "placeholder_2/index.html";
       document.getElementById("iframe-360video-mobile").src = "placeholder_3/index.html";
      }
```

I may figured out why it could not work: I insert this in wordpress fusionbuilder > avada > theme options > Space before  so maybe wordpress don´t let it work normally

Comment: Are you sure about your html structure here? Can you show us how the iframe is built/written?

Comment: <div class="video-container-mobile"><iframe id="iframe-360video-mobile" src="placeholder_1a/index.html" width="100%" height="750" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>

Comment: It probably would have been easier for everyone to paste it in the question body, but it's not the point. I see only one iframe here, why do you expect your js script to "find" two iframes which aren't there? Maybe the html snippet is too narrow in your comment?

Comment: oh i just showed you one iframe cause the settings are the same in all three just the id and src is changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i still don´t know why it doesn´t work, but i don´t need to fix it anymore.Now I dosn´t change my source of the iframe, i change my site when you load it on iphone. Thx for the attention. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add something like:

```
alert(document.getElementById("iframe-vrapp-mobile"))
```

Or do something equivalent in the console. To make the that element ID actually exists and it's an iframe.

Comment: the alert does appear so a wrong id or something isn´t the problem

Comment: The alert will pop anyway, but is it empty or showing something like [Object][object]?